# Is there an easy example of a module which is not projective

Tags: modules, projective-module

Is there an easy example of a module which is not projective?

I found that direct product of $\mathbb Z$ is not projective but its proof is complicated.

Are there any easy examples for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Z$ is a PID and projective modules over PIDs are free, it is clear that every finite abelian group is not projective.

But in fact, you can just use the definition to prove that $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is not projective as $\Bbb Z$-module: consider the quotient map
$$
\pi:\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\longrightarrow\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z.
$$
It is easy to check that there is no map $f:\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ such that $\pi\circ f=1_{\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z}$.

Comment: Why that map does not exist ;If $\pi \circ f=1$ then $f$ is injective which can be if we take the inclusion map from $\mathbb Z_2\to \mathbb Z_4$\

Comment: @learnmore But the image of that inclusion is exactly the kernel of $\pi$ so that $\pi\circ f$ is the zero map, not the identity.

Comment: How? let $f$ be the inclusion then $Im  f=\{[0],[1]\}$ and $ker \pi=\{[0],[2]\}$...please explain

Comment: @learnmore : $\{\bar 0,\bar 1\}$ is not a subgroup of   $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$. There's only one way to embed  $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ as a group and is to send $\bar1\mapsto\bar2$.

Comment: I got that @AdLibitum

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: A free $\mathbb Z$-module, being a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Z$, does not have torsion, so $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is not a direct summand of a free module. One does not need to know the structure of projective modules for this. Moreover, this generilizes to any domain providing examples for which there is no structure theorem available!

Answer (score 0):

Any projective module over a PID (e.g., $\mathbb{Z}$) must be free.